# Handling test data when going from running Selenium tests in series to parallel

Tags: testing, selenium, phpunit, parallel-processing

I'd like to start running my existing Selenium tests in parallel, but I'm having trouble deciding on the best approach due to the way my current tests are written.

The first step in of most of my tests is to get the DB into a clean state and then populate it with the data needed for the rest of the test.  While this is great to isolate tests from each other, if I start running these same Selenium tests in parallel on the same SUT, they'll end up erasing other tests' data.

After much digging, I haven't been able to find any guidance or best-practices on how to deal with this situation.  I've thought of a few ideas, but none have struck me as particularly awesome:

1. Rewrite the tests to not overwrite other tests' data, i.e. only add test data, never erase -- I could see this potentially leading to unexpected failures due to the variability of the database when each test is run.  Anything from a different ordering of tests to an ill-placed failure could throw off the other tests.  This just feels wrong.
2. Don't pre-populate the database -- Instead, create all needed data via Selenium itself.  This would most replicate real-world usage, but would also take significantly longer than loading data directly into the database.  This would probably negate any benefits from parallelization depending on how much test data each test case needs.
3. Have each Selenium node test a different copy of the SUT -- This way, each test would be free to do as it pleases with the database, since we are assume that no other test is touching it at the same time.  The downside is that I'd need to have multiple databases setup and, at the start of each test case, figure out how to coordinate which database to initialize and how to signal to the node and SUT that this particular test case should be using this particular database.  Not awful, but not what I would love to do if there's a better way.
4. Have each Selenium node test a different copy of the SUT, but break up the tests into distinct suites, one suite per node, before run-time  -- Also viable, but not as flexible since over time you'd want to keep going back and even the length of each suite as much as possible.

All in all, none of these seem like clear winners.  Option 3 seems the most reasonable, but I also have doubts about whether that is even a feasible approach.  After researching a bit, it looks like I'll need to write a custom test runner to facilitate running the tests in parallel anyways, but the parts regarding the initial test data still have me looking for a better way.

Anyone have any better ways of handling database initialization when running Selenium tests in parallel?

FWIW, the app and tests suite is in PHP/PHPUnit.

### Update

Since it sounds like the answer I'm looking for is very project-dependent, I'm at least going to attempt to come up with my own solution and report back with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answer and it looks like you've thought out most of it. Also worth considering is to rewrite the tests to use separately partitioned data - this may or may not work depending on your domain (e.g. a separate bank account per node, if it's a banking app). Your pre-population of the DB could be restricted to static reference data, or you could pre-populate the data for each separate 'account'. Again, depends on how easy this is to do for your data.

I'm inclined to vote for 3, though, because database setup is relatively easy to script these days and the hardware requirements probably aren't too high for a small test data suite.

Comment: Partitioning data is an option, but it seems like that would have the same pitfalls as option 1, namely that it is more likely that Test A can screw up the data for Test B, resulting in false positives.  Currently, I'm leaning toward option 3 as well.  Overall, I'm surprised at the lack of info I've been able to find as far as prior work is concerned since this seems like an issue that anyone who wants to parallelize tests involving a database needs to address.